# Custom Breadcrumbs remove duplicates

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

I am using custom breadcrumbs and almost all is working well but a few issues. One problem stated in another question, this problem is that on the landing page of my views I am getting home >> Homme >> Homme. I need to remove the duplicate. I see there is a form in the configuration for breadcrumb visibility. Is this where I solve this problem. I see no other way to do this. Does anyone know or have the code I need?

Answer (score 4):

I think you could use `theme_breadcrumb($variables)` in your `template.php` to remove duplicates.

Code could be something like this:

```
themeName_breadcrumb($variables) {
  [...]
  $breadcrumbs = array_unique($variables['breadcrumb']);
  [...]
}
```

Comment: Ok what goes in the [...] areas. I am not very good with php and really don't understand most of it.

Comment: This is default function implementation, you can look for it in inclides/theme.inc. It is around 1660 line for Drupal 7.10

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I was getting duplicates in my breadcrumb. But they weren't quite duplicates, one would have an anchor element with a title, the other wouldn't, thus I had to check only the html within the anchor element, not the entire row of the array.

I didn't have time to totally debug it. Here's what I did:

```
function [yourtheme]_breadcrumb($variables) {
  // Convenience variable:
  $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];

  //For some reason there are duplicate entries in the breadcrumb, this will remove them
  $flags = array(); 
  foreach($breadcrumb as $key => $bc){
    $startPos = strpos($bc,'>');
    $flag = substr($bc,$startPos);
    if (in_array($flag,$flags)){
      unset($breadcrumb[$key]);
      continue;
    }
    $flags[] = $flag;
  }

  //That's the only relevant code, the rest of this is for another purpose

  // If we have any breadcrumbs:
  if (!empty($breadcrumb)) {
    $breadcrumb[] = drupal_get_title();

    // Convert 'em to a string:
    $breadcrumbs = implode(' <span class="divider">/</span> ', $breadcrumb);
    // Build a heading--here at least, we're following the D7 convention of
    // accompanying menus with invisible headings to aid in text-only navigation:
    $heading = t('You are here');
    // Pattern for output:
    $output_pattern = '<h2 class="element-invisible">%s</h2><ul class="breadcrumb">%s</ul>';
    // Return the markup:
    return sprintf($output_pattern, $heading, $breadcrumbs);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use theme function instead of the preprocess?

```
function THEME_preprocess_breadcrumb(&$variables) {
  $all = array();
  foreach ($variables['breadcrumb'] as $key=>$item) {
    if (preg_match('|href="(.*)"|Ui', $item, $matches)) {
      if (isset($all[$matches[1]])) {
        unset($variables['breadcrumb'][$key]);
      } else {
        $all[$matches[1]] = 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```